# Download files from firebase storage using ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, xmlhttprequest, fetch, firebase-storage

Succesfully i have made to Upload files into firebase storage, but now i want to display all files in table and to have option to download each file.I've read the documentation in firebase but it won't work.When i click the button which function is to get all files and the i want to visualize them in table which users can see:

Show file function:

```
 showFileUrl(){

   storageRef.child('UploadedFiles/').listAll().then(function(res) {
      res.items.forEach(function(folderRef) {
        console.log("folderRef",folderRef.toString());
        var blob = null;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xhr.open("GET", "downloadURL"); 
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = function() 
        {
        blob = xhr.response;//xhr.response is now a blob object
        console.log(blob);
    }
        xhr.send();
      });

    }).catch(function(error) {

    });
  }
```

This is log of the network which i found when debugging.What i need to do to get all data and visualize it in table and to hava a download button and when is pressed to download the file

Network log:
[image]

Storage in firebase:
[image]

Blob object  of the files:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code gets a list of all the files, but it doesn't actually to anything to read the data for each file.

When using the Web client SDK, the only way to get the data for a file is through a download URL as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url). So you'll need to:

1. Loop through all the files you get back from `listAll()` (you're already doing this).
2. Call `getDownloadURL as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url), to get a download URL for each file.
3. Then use another library/function (such as `fetch()`/`XMLHTTPRequest`) to read the data for each file.
4. Alternatively, if your files are images, you can stuff the download URL in an `img` tag as the preview.

Comment: I have some success now i have the blob, how to download and list these files in dataTable